# Why's ExpandableListView call getView many times

Tags: android, performance, expandablelistadapter

I don't know why my expandable called getChildView() and getGroupView() many times.
The problem affects app's performance.
Please help me, here is this adapter.

```
public class ResultsExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<TraceGroupObject> groups;
private int displayMode;
private String TAG = "EXPAND LIST NUTRIENT";

public ResultsExpandableAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<TraceGroupObject> groups, int displayMode) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.groups = groups;
    this.displayMode = displayMode;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    ArrayList<TraceObject> group = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return group.get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}
```

code getChildView

```
// bug
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "Child View (" + groupPosition + "," + childPosition
    // + ") ->" + convertView);
    final TraceObject trace = (TraceObject) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    View row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_row_item, null);
        // Log.i(TAG, "Created View ->" + convertView);
    } else
        row = convertView;

    // init tracebar
    ...

    // implement
    return row;
}
```

hix hix

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    ArrayList<TraceObject> rows = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
    return rows.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groups.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}
```

ac ac getGroupView

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Log.i(TAG, "Group View "+groupPosition +"->" +convertView);
    TraceGroupObject group = (TraceGroupObject) getGroup(groupPosition);

    // create view
    View row;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_item, null);
        // Log.i(TAG, "Created View ->" +convertView);
    } else
        row = convertView;

    // change icon expand
    ...

    return row;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you may get some details from the following link .. so please compare it with your project. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html

Comment: this code has the same problem :(

Comment: What exactly happens? If you scroll the `ExpandableListView` is normal that those methods get called. Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the code where you use the list will also trigger calling those methods.

Comment: getView method alway invoke 4 times for the same parameter
Ex.My ExpandableList has 2 groups. This's logs.
When expandableListView created.
Log:
getGroupView groupPosition=1 invoked
getGroupView groupPosition=2 invoked
getGroupView 2 invoked
getGroupView groupPosition=1 invoked;
getGroupView groupPosition=2 invoked;
getGroupView groupPosition=1 invoked;
getGroupView groupPosition=2 invoked;
getGroupView groupPosition=1 invoked;
getGroupView groupPosition=2 invoked;